# error: could not build Objective-C module 'Quick'

Tags: swift, xcode, testing, swiftui, nimble

Running my Quick and Nimble tests in Xcode and I am now getting this error out of the blue.

```
Build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Quick.build/module.modulemap:2:19: error: umbrella header 'Quick-umbrella.h' not found
  umbrella header "Quick-umbrella.h"
                  ^

error: could not build Objective-C module 'Quick'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

- Quit Xcode
- Clear your derived data. You can find your derived data in here
  ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
- Clean your project (⌘+Shift+K)
- Build your project (⌘+B)

Or ;

---

Another way can fix your issue :

- Go to Xcode Preferences
- Choose Test
- Check the Gather coverage tick as indicated the ss :

[image]

Comment: This did not work. I don't even have the Gather coverage data tick available as well. This could be an issue with the latest update that came with some updates for Xcode 12

Comment: I didn't downvote. Thank you for trying to help. I think I figured it out for some reason I can't use the lower iOS version on my new M1 and didn't realize one was selected so I answered in case anyone else runs into this issue

Answer (score 0):

Issue seemed to be the fact that my M1 doesn't support iOS versions lower than 14. I did not have the correct one selected without realizing and I spent a lot of time trying to figure out why Quick testing wasn't working but my XCTests were.